# Visual Studio 2012 like WPF loading animation

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, when you open the XAML designer you see a loading animation while it loads the designer. While this is happening Visual Studio remains responsive and usable.

In my WPF application, after starting it, the window takes a long while to first appear on the screen. Once it does appear, it's a bit sluggish for a few seconds while WPF loads the controls.

This make for a pretty lousy user experience. It would be great if instead my WPF application's window would appear instantly and show a Visual Studio-like loading animation while the .NET framework would continue loading the rest of it on another thread.

So how would one go about implementing something like this? We know it's possible because Visual Studio does it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Visual Studio is a good example, because it seems to use a different process for the Designer :

[image]

Furthermore, a solution can be to use [multiple UI threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716804/can-does-wpf-have-multiple-gui-threads). There are some articles on the subject, like [Creating a Busy Indicator in a separate thread in WPF](http://abrahamheidebrecht.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/creating-a-busy-indicator-in-a-separate-thread-in-wpf/) or [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127066/Catel-Part-2-of-n-Using-WPF-Controls-and-Themes#PleaseWaitWindow) (see PleaseWaitWindow, which is based on this work : [Multithreaded UI: HostVisual](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing on program startup, simply running some functions on a background thread can dramatically speed things up. I have found in some cases that rewriting functions to use better programming practices can make the program feel more responsive than handling the overhead of keeping a "loading" animation running.

You can also try initializing controls only when they are needed. For example, if you have a combo box which displays a list of fonts, loading that list only when the dropdown is opened will speed up startup. Of course, the user will have a slight delay when opening the dropdown, but they will likely be more forgiving than if they have to wait 15 seconds before they can perform *any* action.

Of course, if the delay is due solely to the WPF rendering engine, then maybe you should implement a splash screen which runs on another thread. This post may be helpful; I used the ideas presented here in my own app: http://thenullreference.com/blog/the-secrets-of-creating-a-animated-splash-screen-in-wpf/.