# Possible to have controls in seperate GUI threads in one wpf window?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm creating a wpf application which reads sensor data from a webserver.
I then plot these data in graphs as I receive them. The data is sent several times a second.

My problem is that I have about 6 graphs I am plotting in the same window.
And it's lagging and updating unevenly, so I guess that is because they are all trying to update the same GUI thread at the same time.

How can I improve this? Can I have the graphs in different GUI threads in the same window, or is there another way to handle this?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716804/can-does-wpf-have-multiple-gui-threads?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post?

Comment: For such a simple scenario you shouldn't have any responsiveness issues. Simply run your app logic on a background thread(s), and update UI using Dispatcher. And if you're not sure what is going - run a profiler.