# What's the best way to create a new UI thread and call back methods on the original thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous

I'm writing a plug-in class for a third-party GUI application. The application calls the `Run` method of my class, passing me a vendor-defined `Context` object. Any methods or properties in this `Context` object **must be called from the current thread** (that is, the application's UI thread).

My plug-in code creates a WPF `Window` and shows it to the user. Some interactions need to call the `Context` object's methods, but some take time to run. This, of course, freezes my UI. Normally, I would call slow methods from a separate thread, but in this case I can't do that because the `Context` object is tied to the application's UI thread.

Here's an example implementation of my Plugin class:

```
public class Plugin
{
    public void Run(Context context)
    {
        // Create a window with my custom user interface
        var window = new MyWindow();

        // Call a slow method when MyButton is clicked
        window.MyButton.Click += (o, e) => context.SlowMethod();

        // Prevent exiting this Run method until the window is closed
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**What are some possible solutions that would allow me to call slow methods in the `Context` object (bound to the UI thread) while having a responsive UI?**

One solution I've come up with is to create a second thread on which to run my UI and use the original thread to call `Context` methods. However, my implementation is rather complex, so I'd like to know if there's a more straightforward way to achieve this.

Here's my current solution:

```
public class Plugin
{
    public void Run(Context context)
    {
        // Get the application's UI thread dispatcher
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        // Create a dispatcher frame to push later
        var frame = new DispatcherFrame();

        // Create a new UI thread (using an StaTaskScheduler)
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var window = new MyWindow();

            // The Click event handler now uses the original
            // thread's dispatcher to run the slow method
            window.MyButton.Click += async (o, e) =>
                await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => context.SlowMethod());

            window.ShowDialog();

            // When the window is closed, end the dispatcher frame
            frame.Continue = false;
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, new StaTaskScheduler(1));

        // Prevent exiting this Run method until the frame is done
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }
}
```

The `StaTaskScheduler` schedules tasks in an STA thread (as required by WPF). It comes from the [Parallel Extensions Extras](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/) library.

Comment: You don't need a new UI thread. Use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` to show a modeless window without waiting for it to close. Run any heavy work on a background thread, possibly using `await Task.Run` so the UI thread won't block while waiting for the background task to finish

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't run the heavy work on a background thread because the `Context` object I want to use (and does the heavy work) must be used in the main UI thread itself.

Comment: The important step to solve the problem should be to contact the developers of this app so that this behavior of letting costly/slow methods run in the UI thread can be corrected in a future software revision. The band-aid for the current situation at hand is probably more or less what you are already doing. Whether you can simplify your logic or not, i don't know, but the general approach follows what you have outlined (and which i guess is more or less in line with the answer given in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716804/can-does-wpf-have-multiple-gui-threads)