# Creating a new UI thread while calling methods on the original thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, f#

I am in a similar situation as this poster ([What's the best way to create a new UI thread and call back methods on the original thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794412/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-new-ui-thread-and-call-back-methods-on-the-origi))

I have an API object which I would like to perform lengthy calculations on, however any properties or methods of this object must be accessed on the current thread (which is the UI thread) or else I get `"Accessing disposed TPS.NET DataObject"` exceptions

Is there an elegant way of accomplishing this using F# async workflows or will I be stuck managing thread dispatchers as in his solution.

For reference, here is his solution to the issue:

```
public class Plugin
{
    public void Run(Context context)
    {
        // Get the application's UI thread dispatcher
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        // Create a dispatcher frame to push later
        var frame = new DispatcherFrame();

        // Create a new UI thread (using an StaTaskScheduler)
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var window = new MyWindow();

            // The Click event handler now uses the original
            // thread's dispatcher to run the slow method
            window.MyButton.Click += async (o, e) =>
                await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => context.SlowMethod());

            window.ShowDialog();

            // When the window is closed, end the dispatcher frame
            frame.Continue = false;
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, new StaTaskScheduler(1));

        // Prevent exiting this Run method until the frame is done
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without know the exact details I would suggest having the Click handler on the main thread and do the following:

- Copy any data needed off the UI into an F# record and passes this into an `async` workflow
- Return immediately after putting the UI into a 'loading' state

The following code is untested but should put you on the right track:

```
    //Get the context of the UI
    let context = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current
    //Gather any needed data from the UI into immutable F# records
    //Put the UI into a 'loading' state
    async {
        // Do work on a different thread
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        let x = 1

        // Switching back to the UI
        do! Async.SwitchToContext context
        //Update UI
        return ()
    }
    |> Async.Start
```

This link should also provide some useful information http://tomasp.net/blog/async-non-blocking-gui.aspx/

EDIT:
If you need to go back and forth between the UI thread and a background thread to gather additional information in the async workflow you can make alternating calls between `do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()` and `do! Async.SwitchToContext context`

Comment: Unfortunately this object from the API has hundreds of fields so this approach isn't really feasible in my case