# Running a Window in another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, splash-screen

A have a WPF application and sometimes I want to show a dialog that performs some heavy calculation so it takes several seconds to show it up. 
To make it clear , I want to show a splash screen with a progress bar or a loader.

I have done the following so far :

```
var splash = new SplashWindow();
splash.Show();
var dialog = new HeavyWindow();
dialog.OnWindowShown += delegate () { splash.Close(); };
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

The `WaitWindow` is just a semitransparent Window with an animation based on Storyboard and `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames`.
 I can provide the code if needed.

The HeavyWindow is a Window that performs some heavy operation and at end it calls `OnWindowShown` (binded to `ContentRendered` event) to close the splash screen.

The problem is that after creating the `HeavyWindow` the animation in `SplashWindow` stops. 
I can understand this behavior since both windows are in the same `GUI` thread. 
The only thing I can't understand is how I can move the `SplashWindow` into a separated thread.
Is there any other solution to the issue?

Comment: maybe Task.Run will help you.

Comment: AFAIK, there's only one UI thread - however, you can move all the heavy work in HeavyWindow's constructor to a task as @Arphile suggested - that should not block the UI thread.

Comment: I've update the code with `Window splash = null; Task taskA = new Task(() => { splash = new WaitWindow(); splash.ShowDialog(); });  taskA.Start();` but in this case the splash window not shown at all. A probably do something wrong. @Arphile, can you please correct me?

Comment: Just use var T = Task.Run( () => { ///TASKS/// }; T.Wait() if you wanna wait until task finished.

Comment: if you need to use ShowDialog, Dispatcher.Invoke will help you.

Comment: if not, jsut use Show() for that.

Comment: Ideally, you should move the heavy work off the Main/GUI thread. However if you really want two GUI threads/Dispatchers, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716804/can-does-wpf-have-multiple-gui-threads)

Comment: _" I want to show a dialog that performs some heavy calculation"_ - Just no! Use the Dialog for Display only. For computations use a Task + Progress/IProgress, to update the Dialog's UI Elements. Something along this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872887/982149 Or get it from the master himself Stephen Cleary: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Comment: *"how can I move the SplashWindow into separated thread"* - create thread, run it and then inside that thread construct and show window.

Comment: Maybe we all think in a wrong direction and this is what you want? - [how to add a splash screen to a wpf application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application) and further: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: ^^ Ah, no. Forget it. They can only show images... :(

Comment: @Arphile Why would you want to spawn a task via `Task.Run()` only to `Wait()` it?

Comment: @Arphile Never use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.  It will lead to a GUI thread lock-up.  Use `BeginInvoke`

Comment: The only solution that works here is to move the "heavy job" on a separated thread (Task, Thread, BackgroundWorker, whatever) otherwise the UI will still stuck. WPF has just 1 thread delegate to render the UI (the Dispatcher thread) so creating a thread to render the window will not boost your solution because the "other thread" needs to synchronize with the unique Dispatcher thread.

Comment: @Sinatr _"create thread, ... inside that thread construct and show window"_ - ensure the thead is a STA thread of course

Comment: If you were to use MvvM you would have had a task in your view model that would do "heavy work" in the background and then just flip a bool property which would trigger a ContentControl to be shown with animation, job done. Why do you insist on making this hard work for yourself? That approach maybe worked with WinForms, WPF is much more sophisticated.